# PPA 404 error when installing Flux on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, software-installation

Whenever I try and Install Flux (in terminal) and I type in "`sudo apt-get update`", it says:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was no official `flex gui` for saucy.So try to install flex-gui from raring.Follow the simple steps given below to install flex-gui in ubuntu 13.10.

- Run the below commands,(if you already do this,skip to the next step)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Run the below command to edit `kilian-f_lux-raring.list` file,

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kilian-f_lux-saucy.list
  ```

  And delete all the lines in that file ,add the below lines and save the file.

  ```
  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu raring main
  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kilian/f.lux/ubuntu raring main
  ```
- Update the software repositories and then install `flex-gui`

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install fluxgui
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Did you get the links from here:  http://justgetflux.com/linux.html

I noticed a set of instructions there.  The ppa you have above does go 404.  Maybe try the instructions on the site I linked.

Edit:  I noticed this comment on the page so I think this is your issue.  Check the page in the link.:

> fluxgui has not been officially updated for Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy salamander) yet.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know, I did so I just have to wait until flux for 13.10 to come out.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RedShift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) instead. It is in official repositories.

`sudo apt-get install redshift-gtk`

**Setup config**

`cd ~/.config
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reversiblean/redshift-config/master/redshift.conf`

Sample Config File: https://github.com/reversiblean/redshift-config/blob/master/redshift.conf